# jquery not adding class when inputs are not empty

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating a simple function which shows a login button when both inputs are not empty, however, jQuery does not seem to want to allow me.

I have checked to make sure the jQuery API that I am using is up to date and correct, but nothing seems to be out of the ordinary.

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var u = $.trim($("#_jq-loC1").val());
    var p = $.trim($('#_jq-loC2').val());
    var l = $('#_jq-slO1');

    if(u.length > 0 && p.length > 0) {
        l.addClass('slO1');
    } else {
        l.removeClass('slO1');
    }
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="_jq-loC1" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
<input type="password" name="password" id="_jq-loC2" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
<input style="width: 0.1px; height:0.1px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden;" id="login" type="submit" value="">
<div class="send-login-container">
    <label class="send-login" id="_jq-slO1" for="login"></label>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.slO1{
    width: 54px;
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Try with  `$(l).addClass('slO1');`

Comment: @MdDinar didn't work, sorry :/

Comment: Your code work fine. See [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ph3q75c2/)

Comment: How are you tracking the change? Where is the event I mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your code is only executed on the page load.
So if you change the content of your inputs later, nothing will be executed.

You need to watch changes in your inputs.

In your `$(document).ready()` you can replace your code by :

```
var toggleSubmit = function () {
    var u = $.trim($("#_jq-loC1").val());
    var p = $.trim($('#_jq-loC2').val());
    var l = $('#_jq-slO1');

    if(u.length > 0 && p.length > 0) {
        l.addClass('slO1');
    } else {
        l.removeClass('slO1');
    }
};

$('#_jq-loC1').on('change', function () {
    toggleSubmit();
});

$('#_jq-loC2').on('change', function () {
    toggleSubmit();
});

// Check on page load
toggleSubmit();
```

Comment: Hi, it is semi-working.. The user will have to click off of one of the inputs to display the login button. How would I make it so that they only have to enter something into both fields? :)

Comment: You can bind to the `keyup` event instead of `change`. The verification will be done each time the user will type something.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is because you are attaching functions on document.ready, you have to do it on text field changes. I'm giving you solution on fiddle. You can try it

```js
$('#_jq-loC2,#_jq-loC1').on('change',function() {
    var u = $.trim($("#_jq-loC1").val());
    var p = $.trim($('#_jq-loC2').val());
 
    if(u.length > 0 && p.length > 0) {
       alert('Do someting');
    } else {
       //to do something if empty
    }
});
```

```css
.slO1{
    width: 54px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" name="username" id="_jq-loC1" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
<input type="password" name="password" id="_jq-loC2" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
<input style="width: 0.1px; height:0.1px; opacity: 1; overflow: hidden;" id="login" type="submit" value="Submit">
<div class="send-login-container">
    <label class="send-login" id="_jq-slO1" for="login"></label>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with

```
if( (u.length > 0) && (p.length > 0) ) {
  // Code
}
```

As far as I know, the **AND** selector wants two statements, so you have to group your expression together.

Comment: I'm almost certain that isn't required.. But, I'll try it anyway

Comment: That's not needed and also considered as a bad practice. `u.length > 0` is a single expression.